# Java JButton Need to work only one time

Tags: java, jbutton

I can't understand, how can i do that, if button clicked, it only cheks Playerlevel one time and upgrades. Not till not enought money?

1.Try

```
 if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Upgrade LVL")) {  
                if (car.Playerlevel == 1){
                    if (car.money >= 2){
                        car.money -= 2;
                        car.Playerlevel +=1;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained 1 Player Level", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    if (car.money < 2){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You dont have enought money. This Upgrade costs 100", "No Money", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}                
                    }           
                if (car.Playerlevel == 2){
                    if (car.money >= 2){
                        car.money -= 2;
                        car.Playerlevel +=1;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained 2 Player Level", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                    if (car.money < 2){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You dont have enought money. This Upgrade costs 200", "No Money", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}                
                    }
                if (car.Playerlevel == 3){
                    if (car.money >= 2){
                        car.money -= 2;
                        car.Playerlevel +=1;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained 3 Player Level", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                    if (car.money < 2){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You dont have enought money. This Upgrade costs 300", "No Money", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}                
                    }
                if (car.Playerlevel == 4){
                    if (car.money >= 2){
                        car.money -= 2;
                        car.Playerlevel +=1;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained 4 Player Level", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                    if (car.money < 2){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You dont have enought money. This Upgrade costs 400", "No Money", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}                
                    }
                if (car.Playerlevel == 5){
                    if (car.money >= 2){
                        car.money -= 2;
                        car.Playerlevel +=1;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained 5 Player Level", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                    if (car.money < 2){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You dont have enought money. This Upgrade costs 500", "No Money", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}                
                    }
                if (car.Playerlevel == 6){
                    if (car.money >= 2){
                        car.money -= 2;
                        car.Playerlevel +=1;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained 6 Player Level", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                    if (car.money < 2){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You dont have enought money. This Upgrade costs 600", "No Money", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}                
                    }
                if (car.Playerlevel == 7){
                    if (car.money >= 2){
                        car.money -= 2;
                        car.Playerlevel +=1;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained 7 Player Level", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                    if (car.money < 2){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You dont have enought money. This Upgrade costs 700", "No Money", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}                
                    }
                if (car.Playerlevel == 8){
                    if (car.money >= 2){
                        car.money -= 2;
                        car.Playerlevel +=1;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained 8 Player Level", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                    if (car.money < 2){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You dont have enought money. This Upgrade costs 800", "No Money", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}                
                    }
                if (car.Playerlevel == 9){
                    if (car.money >= 2){
                        car.money -= 2;
                        car.Playerlevel +=1;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained 9 Player Level", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}
                    if (car.money < 2){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You dont have enought money. This Upgrade costs 900", "No Money", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}                
                    }
                if (car.Playerlevel == 10){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have gained MAX Player Level", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}                            
            }
```

2.Try

```
if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Upgrade LVL")) {           
            for (int i =0; i <11; i++){                 
                   if (car.Playerlevel == i){
                    if (car.money >= i*2){
                        car.money -= i*2;
                        car.Playerlevel +=1;                   
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You have purchased " + i + " Player level.", "Congralations", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);}                          
                    else{                           
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You dont have enought money. This Upgrade costs 100*lvl", "No Money", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}               
                   }
            }
        }
```

No one of these tries, don't work. I just need to button work only one time, when pressed. I tried with brake; but it didn't worked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this is to revert the loop. Instead of

```
 for (int i =0; i <11; i++)
```

use

```
 for (int i=10; i>= 0; i--)
```

The problem is that you change the playerLevel variable while iterating. Above idea of mine works because you only increase levels and never decrease them. A more general approach would be to store the result in a local variable and use this after the loop to set the playerLevel.

Actually, if your loop is not more complicated as the one you showed, you can as well erase the loop and use playerLevel instead of i.

Comment: The best way of saying "thank you" is to accept my answer ;-).